# Unable to import wordpress theme unit test data

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

Everytime i am unable to import wordpress test data from here.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Unit_Test

I am using xampp, sometimes its failed to import.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide error details.

Comment: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-http.php on line 1511

Answer (score 2):

Find class-wp-http-curl.php in that directory (C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes) And before line 240 , input set_time_limit (5000);

```
set_time_limit (5000);
curl_exec( $handle );
$theHeaders = WP_Http::processHeaders( $this->headers, $url );
$theBody = $this->body;
$bytes_written_total = $this->bytes_written_total;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @rat.. your answer helped me!

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is in the error your provide `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded`.

You should edit your server PHP.ini to extend this 60 second limit. In example to 240 seconds.

`max_execution_time = 240 ;`

Comment: Now this error will come: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-http.php on line 1511

Comment: It's the same error, so you didn't updated the config (remember to restart Apache after every change of the config)

Comment: Nope. still it will through that error. Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-http.php on line 1511

Comment: This answer should be selected as correct. It's the same error, and is a problem with your PHP config.

Answer (score 0):

Find class-http.php in that directory (C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes)
And before line 1511 OR 1510, input `set_time_limit (5000);`
the `5000` is the seconds. so the larger the number, the longer the maximum execution time will be.So at line 1509 it should look like this...

```
    set_time_limit (5000);
    curl_exec( $handle );
    $theHeaders = WP_Http::processHeaders( $this->headers, $url );
    $theBody = $this->body;
    $bytes_written_total = $this->bytes_written_total;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Max Execution Time exceeded error while importing Wordpress Theme Unit Testing Data

**If Nothing works, try it.**

wp-includes > deprecated.php line number 3636; 
WordPress V: 4.8.2

function wp_get_http( $url, $file_path = false, $red = 1 ) {
    _deprecated_function( **FUNCTION**, '4.4.0', 'WP_Http' );

```
@set_time_limit( 60 );
```

if ( $red > 5 )
  return false  ………………….

> change @set_time_limit( 1260 );

It's work for me